# Tensorflow 2.0 model using tf.function very slow and is recompiling every time the train count changes. Eager runs about 4x faster

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I have models built from uncompiled keras code and am trying to run them through a custom training loop.

The TF 2.0 eager (by default) code runs about 30s on a CPU (laptop). When I create a keras model with wrapped tf.function call methods, it is running much, much slower and appears to take a very long time to start, particularly the "first" time.

For example, in the tf.function code the initial train on 10 samples takes 40s, and the follow up one on 10 samples takes 2s.

On 20 samples, the initial takes 50s and the follow up takes 4s.

The first train on 1 sample takes 2s and follow up takes 200 ms.

So it looks like each call of train is creating a *new graph* where the complexity scales with the train count!?

I am just doing something like this:

```py
@tf.function
def train(n=10):
    step = 0
    loss = 0.0
    accuracy = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
        step += 1
        d, dd, l = train_one_step(model, opt, data)
        tf.print(dd)
        with tf.name_scope('train'):
            for k in dd:
                tf.summary.scalar(k, dd[k], step=step)
        if tf.equal(step % 10, 0):
            tf.print(dd)
    d.update(dd)
    return d
```

Where the model is `keras.model.Model` with a `@tf.function` decorate `call` method as per the examples.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I analyzed this behavior of `@tf.function` here [Using a Python native type](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/04/03/dissecting-tf-function-part-2/#using-a-python-native-type).

In short: the design of `tf.function` does not automatically do the boxing of Python native types to `tf.Tensor` objects with a well-defined `dtype`.

If your function accepts a `tf.Tensor` object, on the first call the function is analyzed, the graph is built and associated with that function. In every non-first call, if the `dtype` of the `tf.Tensor` object matches, the graph is reused.

But in case of using a Python native type, the graphg is being built **every time the function is invoked with a different value**.

In short: design your code to use `tf.Tensor` everywhere instead of the Python variables if you plan to use `@tf.function`.

`tf.function` is not a wrapper that magically accelerates a function that works well in eager mode; is a wrapper that requires to design the eager function (body, input parameters, dytpes) understanding what will happen once the graph is created, in order to get real speed ups.

Comment: This is great ... should be a big warning in the docs I guess. If there is one, I have definitely missed it.

Comment: One thing I just don't understand is why they have the tf.function examples here https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/effective_tf2 ... that include model etc in the args if this is a known problem with autograph.

Comment: passing a model (that is a keras object), a tf.data.dataset or any tf.* obejct is not a problem at all. The performance decreases only if you pass a Python native type

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Comment: Thanks, @nessuno. I know you were referring to native *numeric* types, but I'd also like to add that a list of tensors works fine even though lists are also considered native types in python.