# Performance of tensorflow built-in training loops vs customized training loops

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I have justed coded a subclassing model in tensorflow 2.0 using tf.keras.Model and I use a cumstomized training loop. Training takes for ever! I came across this tensorflow example [VAE](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models), which is very similar to my model and how I customized my training loop. I have run the tensorflow example in the link using both the customized and built-in training function and the former takes about 90 secs for 10 epochs, while the latter only takes 20 secs.

Why is the customized loop slower and how can it be improved to train as fast as the built-in fit function? Here is a link to run just the VAE in the link above [run_vae](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ge0S8LudiLHVcrsGMwcmp0pBc-hetC5S)

```
problem for my own model in tensorflow example
```

Comment: Use `@tf.function` decorator correctly.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal do you mean that the customized training loop should be part of the class object using a `@tf.function`

Comment: @moderators the difference in performance that I asked, is in one example in the tensorflow website (link), and not only in my own model.

Comment: The problem is solve, as pointed by @SusmitAgrawal, by adding a `@tf.function`  to the weight update function  in my code. This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711115/tensorflow-2-0-model-using-tf-function-very-slow-and-is-recompiling-every-time-t  explains the problem. As mentioned in one comment in the link, this behavior should be mention in the tensorflow documentation!